# MongoDB Find and Modify With GraphQL

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I am working on GraphQL mutation and need help here. My document looks like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc02db357146d0c385d4988"),
    "item_type" : "CategoryMapping",
    "id" : null,
    "CategoryGroupName" : "Mystries & Thriller",
    "CustomCategory" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Private Investigator",
            "MappedBisacs" : [ 
                "investigator", 
                "Privately owned", 
                "Secret"
            ]
        },
{
            "name" : "Crime Investigator",
            "MappedBisacs" : [ 
                "crime investigator", 
                "crime thriller"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

UI

- Allow user to update MappedBisacs through list of checkbox. So user can add/update or delete list of bisacs.

Problem - When client send GraphQL query like following;

```
mutation {
  CategoryMapping_add(input: {CategoryGroupName: "Mystries & Thriller", CustomCategory: [{name: "Crime Investigator", MappedBisacs: ["investigator", "dafdfdaf", "dafsdf"]}]}) {
    clientMutationId
  }
}
```

I need to find Specific custom category and update its bisac array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got it, but this more a doubt on `MongoDb` than on `GraphQL` itself. First you must find the document that you want (I would use the `id` of the document instead of `CategoryGroupName`), then you can update this array in several ways. For example, after you found the document, you could simply access the array content and spread into a new one adding this new data from your mutation, and save this object with the `update` method. (if you simply want to add new data without removing any)
So, it depends on the case.

Check: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

Hope it helps! :)